# 12" MacBook battery is dead after 386 cycles

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have an early 2015 12" MacBook 512 GB SSD with 8 GB RAM.

I have used my it nearly daily since I bought it brand new. I have never exposed it to high temperature, always working in AC room with a temperature around 24 degrees Celsius. Never worked in bed, but always on the table. I always care of my computer in the best possible way.

The Battery has major issues, the battery is sometimes charging till 100%, sometimes it drops to 20% and charging only till this number. Sometimes I can run my MacBook without charger plugged and sometimes it won't even start if it's not plugged.

The battery side is probably a little bit inflated so the case doesn't fit together as on another side. Looks like the battery somehow got bigger.

Any ideas why is this happening? And if Apple will care it like some hardware issues from their side so they will change it? The battery is only 386 of 1000 cycles they told me so it is absolutely outrageous on the machine for $2000 at that time.

Comment: Take care of that battery ASAP!! Putting it off will cause further damage to the case and other components inside.

Comment: Apple should definitely take care of this, regardless of AppleCare status.

Comment: Hope so.. we will see what they will tell me ... Thank you for answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inflated/bulging battery is a safety risk and you should get it repaired ASAP. The reason for this could be anything from manufacturing defects to improper care.

If you got AppleCare when you bought your Mac, you may still be able to replace the battery for free. Otherwise, Apple won't change the battery for free, as warranties only last one year.(see [here](https://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/products/embedded-mac-warranty-us.html))

If you schedule a repair without AppleCare or warranty, it can cost anywhere from $129-199, depending on your Mac's model. You can schedule a repair [here](https://support.apple.com/mac/repair/service).

Or, if you are willing to take the risk, you can replace the battery on your own using an [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/) guide.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As long as i know, i did everything, that apple say on the website for the proper use of the battery. 

Will try to find the closest apple and try to solve this thing... but i guess at 386 cycles it is clearly a manufacturing problem. So i hope they will make it without fee... Thank you once again... for answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Bulging batteries mean only one thing- buildup of gas inside. The gases are produced due to electrochemical oxidation of the electrolyte.

There's also no single cause for a swollen battery. Some are due to manufacturing defects, others are caused by the age of the battery, and still other cases can be caused by misuse, such as not properly exercising the battery over time, or by using the wrong power charger.

If Apple will care, I do not know, they must not when it is outside the warranty but it depends, in your case it is clearly a manufacturing defect and a Safety risk that should not have happened.

Do not wait to have it fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, we are currently in Vietnam so I will find the closest authorized apple or i will just wait 7 days till we reach big chinas city. The battery still says it needs to be replaced but it is safe to use... What im writing here, its not safe to use at all.... 

Recently is has even started to shut down my computer if im running like the final cut pro or just youtube.

Comment: It is not safe to continue using it.